# How to properly step down the voltage of a DC+AC signal that then goes inside a pin of a PIC?

Tags: pic, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, filter

The reason of the question is because i don't know if this is the correct way of regulating a signal that goes inside the pin of a PIC that accepts a signal that goes till 3V3.

In the following image it's the circuit i have, where `DATA_IN` is the input signal:

[image]

And then in this graph with the green light is the `LOOP PROTOCOL` signal

[image]

With the blue color the `DATA_IN` signal:

[image]

I was thinking a diode would be enough to step down the voltage, to the levels we want, which is starting from 0 to 3V3.

Opinions?

Comment: The `LOOP PROTOCOL` signal is a series of DC voltage pulse with an offset around 23 Volt, same with `DATA_IN`. So, where's the AC signal?

Comment: Hi @Unknown i dont want DATA_IN to be a completly AC signal, but a signal that starts at 0 and goes to 3V3 (this will then go to a pin port of a microcontroller)

Comment: Most microcontroller data sheets caution about letting a digital input pin hover near half-Vdd. If **LOOP PROTOCOL** is missing or idle, **DATA_IN** will sit near half-Vdd via those two 220k resistors. This could cause excess microcontroller current and heating.

Comment: thanks for the advice @glen_geek

Comment: @Nmaster88 okay, but the waveform that you're showing above is not an AC signal, that is DC signal. There must be some negative voltage in that graph if it was AC. Perhaps you're asking on how to scale down a DC signal. To properly sense an AC signal, shifting or adding the DC offset is required to remove the negative voltage, not only scaling.

Comment: @Unknown123 you're right. The question is wrong as it is. Yes, what i want is to scale down the DC signal. I want it to go from 0 to 3V3.

Comment: Are your input signal fixed from 23.4V to 32.4V or is it dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! :-).
This is a MUCH better attempt than most people make.
For guaranteed voltage levels you want Vpin ideally inside Vdd-Gnd range and at worst not more than 0.3V above Vdd or below ground.  Older data sheets tended to use hard Vdd/gnd limits. More recent ones tend towards a typically 0.3V over/under voltage allowance. Nothing has changed in most cases except a willingness to push the limits more closely with experience of consequences.  Even say 10 uA of current in body diodes CAN produce bizarre results in SOME cases SOMETIMES.

Place an opposite polarity diode = D4 across D3.
This causes the pin to track Vin - a diode drop in both polarities.

Maybe make both D4 and D3 Silicon and not Schottky (slightly higher Vf).

Place two resistors from PIC pin to Vdd and ground. These provide a load when the diodes are driven.

Report back.

If essential a resistor network on the pin side of D3 D4 can better ensure the pin is never illegally driven BUT what you have plus the above should work well.

This can be done with a few less parts if component count, cost and space are at an utter premium.

Comment: Thanks, right now i'm thinking about another solution  that involves using a transistor BJT but will then invert the signal at the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your method clamps the input signal to Vdd (3V3) + a diode drop (0.7V) or GND - a diode drop.

This makes a lot of sense. I/O signals that exceed those limits will be limited and not cause any damage to following circuitry.

One thing to be aware of is that it's important for the input signals to swing close to GND to ensure that correct logic levels are maintained.

Note this interface may not have the 'speed' of a 'normal' interface where outputs and inputs are connected directly instead of with a resistance of 47k ohms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an optoisolator.  There are several topologies but the ones with an LED on "high" voltage side would require a voltage divider followed by an inline resistor.  On the low voltage side, you will get a clean, no-more than 3.3V signal.

With an input voltage range of 23.4 to 32.4 V, a divider of about 10 (depending on the LED on the isolator) should do the trick.